# Serialization of arbitrary objects on Android

Tags: java, android, serialization, clojure, clone

I would like to automatically dump a Var object resulting from the Clojure's initialization - i.e. a complex object that does not implement Serializable and nests several other objects like that.

I experimented with a few frameworks, but they did not work (XStream produced XML with some null values), were not supported by Android (Kryo requires java.misc.Unsafe which has a limited implementation on Android; JBoss Serialization also requires something not available on Android...), or were not automatic (GSon requires to define type tokens for generics...).

Efficiency is not important (it's only an experiment / for debugging).

Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: You could do it yourself using reflection and recursion.

Comment: Do you mean to iterate over all involved objects and change them to implement Serializable, and then use a standard object serialization?

Comment: No I mean you could implement your own object serialization for arbitrary objects. You just visit each object and all it's attributes and convert them to xml (or any format you want).

Comment: did you try edn or json in clojure initialization?

Comment: I tried to serialize it with GSon that produces json - but it ends up with "Unable to invoke no-args constructor for interface clojure.lang.IPersistentMap"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pr-str` to convert to string:

```
user=> (pr-str [:map {:a [1 2 3]} "string"])
"[:map {:a [1 2 3]} \"string\"]"
```

and read back using edn:

```
user=> (require '[clojure.edn :as edn])
user=> (edn/read-string "[:map {:a [1 2 3]} \"string\"]")
[:map {:a [1 2 3]} "string"]
```

or just `read-string`:

```
user=> (read-string "[:map {:a [1 2 3]} \"string\"]")
[:map {:a [1 2 3]} "string"]
```

**NOTE** that `read-string` is unsafe for reading from "untrusted sources" - http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/1.3.0/clojure.core/read

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it is not what I am after - I would like to dump the initialized Var, so that I don't need to reinitialize Clojure again. So, it should possibly work for an arbitrary "complex object that does not implement Serializable and nests several other objects like that".

Comment: To serialize arbitrarily complex objects is a Turing complete problem. You will not find a general solution. Using edn and immutible / stateless objects is a very clean alternative, it will require refactoring code but that refactoring is almost guaranteed to be an improvements.

Comment: I mentioned "it's only an experiment / for debugging": obviously, I could find the original source code (I only have a bytecode) and refactor all that hierarchy of hundreds of objects. But I'm looking for a quick one-off solution and do not mind if it's dirty.